# Enforce compile time maximum value to a integral constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, class-template, compile-time-type-checking

I have a template class like so:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int size>
class Array 
{
public:
  static const unsigned int SIZE = size;
  // ...
private:
  T data[SIZE];
};
```

Is there a way to add compile-time checks such that the size of an `Array<T,XXXX>` never exceeds a certain value?

Like if that value was `512`, this shouldn't compile:

`Array<int, 1000> arr;`

---

This idea of C++ifiying my code is new to me, so I'm open to any guides or further learning online to help with this since I didn't even know what to google for this. Everything I tried seemed way off.

Comment: `static_assert(size < 512);`

Comment: Perfect. Please add this as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to add compile-time checks such that the size of an `Array<T,XXXX>` never exceeds a certain value?

You can use [`requires`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/requires) in C++20 for this

```
template<typename T, unsigned int size> requires (size < 512)
class Array 
{
       // .....
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) the condition inside the class definition with a meaningful message to the user.

```
template<typename T, unsigned int size>
class Array 
{
     static_assert(size < 512, "Array size exceeded");
     // ....
};
```